# Prove that when a fixed-point interation function of class p converges, if all the derivatives up to p-1 are equal, they're all zero.

Tags: limits, derivatives, fixed-point-theorems

The function $\phi(x) \in C^p([a,b])$ and $x_0 \in [a,b]$ meet the conditions for convergence of the fixed-point iteration method, that is:
$$\phi([a,b]) \subseteq [a,b] \\ \phi'(x) < 1 \mspace{5mu} ,\mspace{15mu} \forall x \in [a,b]$$

Let $\alpha \in ]a,b[$ be the solution of $\phi(\alpha) = \alpha$. Prove that if:
$$\phi'(\alpha)=\phi''(\alpha)=...=\phi^{(p-1)}(\alpha) = \beta$$

Then:
$$\beta=0$$

---

I thought about using:
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty}\left(\frac{x_{k+1}-\alpha}{x_k-\alpha}\right) = \phi'(\alpha)$$
But it got me nowhere. I also thought about using the Taylor polynomial of $\phi$ around the point $\alpha$ but it didn't seem to take me anywhere either.

Comment: I think you are missing an assumption. The function $\phi(x)=x/2$ with $a=-1,b=1, \alpha=0$ and $p=2$ satisfies your assumptions, but not the conclusion.

Comment: I think you might be right. The exercise was sent to me in an image so I think they might have left some of it out by mistake. I've asked if there was anything missing, I'll let you know when they answer. Thank you for the help!

Comment: The longer I think about this, the less I see what the missing assumption might be. Look at $\phi(x)=(e^x-1)/2$. Then $\phi^{(k)}(0)=1/2$ for all $k>0$, but $1/2\neq 0$. Also, this function is as nice as it gets (analytic, strictly convex, etc).

Comment: You were right, there's stuff missing. Sadly, they don't have the rest of the exercise. Thanks again for your help!